# QuickfixJ can't send a message with an accents char in tag 58

Tags: quickfixj

when i try to sending a fix message with accents char in tag 58, the message was not send and the opposite system ask to resend the message from sequence 125.
some tag of message:
34=125
58=test message with accent **é**.

Comment: Which version of QFJ are you using? I suspect you are sending the message but the opposite side might calculate a wrong checksum  (given you are using a recent QFJ version ). Can you add the message from the message log and relevant parts from your event log?

Comment: i use a quickfixj-all 1.5.2-bd with FIX 4.2. this un example of message:
**8=FIX.4.2|9=351|35=D|34=445|43=Y|49=SNEDER|52=20220420-13:20:01.401|56=TARGET|122=20220420-13:19:07|11=REFERENCE|15=USD|21=3|22=4|38=15000|40=2|44=0.55|48=ISIN|54=1|55=ISIN|58=0.55 cours limité|60=20220420-11:19:06.000|100=PC|109=MY_CLIENT_ID|207=PC|432=20220420|78=1|79=005|80=1|10=173|**

Comment: That version is too old and cannot correctly handle special characters IIRC. I think you need to update at least to 1.6.0 or even 2.0.0. Need to check the release notes.